# Accept-Encoding GZIP Http Client Scrambled Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I was making an HttpClient request and got the Status 200 and a normal XML response, but I don't use AWAIT, I put a .Result at the end of the method. Now I started to receive a response with Status 200, but the content is scrambled, encoded (example: "\ u \ b \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ n"). Does anyone know how to tell me how to solve this?

Because I can't convert the answer to the object I want.

```
using (var requisicao = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        requisicao.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {V.P014_ClienteKey}");
                        requisicao.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization-Raw-Data", V.P014_ClienteFraseCriptografia);
                        requisicao.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization-Encrypted-Data", "3241880a48c0c26733168cfd558a5bdfbd54a3079a77871065f2c32ac107356f3d77bd14488c669c26380953a1d3df40f7c2cc4ff67d73f65ec71ab4b5769a69");
                        requisicao.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

                        var resposta = requisicao.GetAsync($"https://conciliation.stone.com.br/v1/merchant/{V.P014_CodigoCliente}/conciliation-file/{DataRef}").Result;

                        if (resposta.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BonzayBO.DTO.Conciliacao.Stone.Conciliation));
                            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result))
                            {
                                var result = (BonzayBO.DTO.Conciliacao.Stone.Conciliation)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
                                XML.LoadXml(resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                             }
                         }
                      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below for Accept-Encoding;

```
using (var client = new HttpClient( new HttpClientHandler
{
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        }))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://conciliation.stone.com.br");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1/merchant/{V.P014_CodigoCliente}/conciliation-file/{DataRef}");
            
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // or response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode
            {
                return null;
            }

            // deserialize operation
            return ...
}
```

Comment: Hello @gabriel, Glad to hear that I helped solve the problem. And I hope other community members can help them resolve the similar problem quickly, please accept kindly - See [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for your understanding, have a nice day.